# Hide(); и show();  ---- Проблемы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подключения:

```
<link href="/assets/templates/medica/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/118369844029235281122/posts" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='[(site_url)]assets/js/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='[(site_url)]assets/js/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js_form/jquery-ui-1.10.1._VSPLUVAUSHCHEI__And_Ephect_custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js_form/form_efect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/baner/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/baner/css/iview.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/baner/css/skin 5/style.css" />
        <script src="/assets/baner/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#my_form').hide();
$('#formHide').click(function(){
    if ($('#formHide').text() == 'Зарегистрироватся'){
        $('#my_form').show('explode',{},1000);  //('explode',1000)
        $('#formHide').text('Отмена');
    }
    else{
        $('#my_form').hide('scale',{},1000); //('scale',1000)
        $('#formHide').text('Зарегистрироватся');
    }
}); 
});
```

Проблема в том что на странице функции не работают , если убрать эффекты и прописать `hide();` или `show();` тогда функции работают ..... В чём может быть причина? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не нужно постить сюда простыни с кодом — есть же http://jsfiddle.net!

Comment: сори я только учусь ... может подскажет все-таки кто в чем сдесь моя ошибка?

Comment: @artuska ещё раз, НАДО постить код сюда, jsfiddle чтобы показать повторяемость ошибки, это сторонний сервис и если с него код исчезнет, вопрос станет бесполезным для сообщества. кроме того гугл может не найти вопрос без кода. 

@Vitaliisss всё нормально, единственное, что может быть надо чуть более релевантный код выдавать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все должно работать, смотрите сообщения в консоли, возможно ваш js файл jquery-ui-`1.10.1._VSPLUVAUSHCHEI__And_Ephect_custom.js` производит какую-то ошибку. или тоже что-то делает с эффектами (он и называется как-то так), ещё может jquery поновее ? 1.4.4 уж совсем древняя. У вас  оно кстати дважды подключено (может надо один раз).

**Решение - jquery вторую убрать, первую сделать более новой версии** (1.7.7 что-ли). проблема в том что вы грузите jquery после jqueryui.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $effects = $('#effects');
    $('#hide').click(
    function () {
        $($effects).hide('scale', {}, 1000);
    });
    $('#show').click(
    function () {
        $($effects).show('explode', {}, 1000);
    });
});
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/5q92t/1/)

Comment: @eicto спасибо огромное очень помог..... еще раз спасибо!!!

Answer (score -1):

У вас есть документация по jQuery. Можно зайти на сайт документации, найти функцию [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) и [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) и посмотреть, как с ними работать, а именно, какие параметры эти функции могут принимать. Элементарно же.

Comment: там подключена jqueryui с эффектами, http://jqueryui.com/hide/

Comment: А, тогда ок.